# Why is paragraph tag overflowing instead of creating a new line?

Tags: html, css

Whenever I create a P tag and fill it with code it overflows instead of creating new lines.
CSS:

```
#main {
width: 700px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#main #top h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 48px;
    margin: 0;
}
#main #menucontainer  {
    width: 700px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#main #menucontainer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 255px;
}
#main #menucontainer ul li a {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #000;
}
#main #menucontainer ul li a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
#main #menucontainer ul li a.current {
    background-color:#CCC;
    color: black;
}


#main #footer {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Home</title>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="main">

<div id="top">

<h1>Home</h1>

</div>

<div id="menucontainer">

<ul>

<li><a href="index.php" class="current">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="submit.php">Submit</a></li>

<li><a href="contactus.php" style="border-right:solid 1px black;">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>

<p>asdfhsadfkjasdjkcnakdsjnfkjdsanckjdsanfjkhaskjcnjksdankjfhasdknjcnadsjkfhkjsdhfkjncjsdnfjaksdhfkjadshfjkcndasjknf</p>

<div id="footer">2011</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add `word-wrap:break-word` to your paragraph style

Answer (score 11):

Your text is a single word so there is no where for the `<p>` tag to break the text into a new line.

If you want to force the line to wrap without regard to the text it self try setting a specific width for your `<p>` tags ( by either using width:inherit or using an actual size ) and then setting the white-space attribute to pre-wrap.

```
p { 
    width:inherit; /* width: 100px; */
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

More information on the [white-space attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp).

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word` is also required.

Answer (score 3):

The `p` tag will only make a new line on line-breaking characters like spaces, hyphens, and other punctuation. (Try inserting a space in the middle of your long asdf line.)

You might try the options suggested at http://gojomo.blogspot.com/2005/03/cross-browser-invisible-word-break-in.html if you want to create invisible word breaks.